# Using AccessKey in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am confused. Should I use AccessKey to create a shortcut or use plain javascript to create shortcuts on the buttons on my asp.net page. What's the difference in the two approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AccessKey is JavaScript Independent, but it only moves focus to element. It Does not fire any actions. And is limited to Alt- combinations. That is for ie4.0+